# System.JSON does not throw exception for malformed JSON input

Tags: c#, json

I am new to using .NET System.JSON. Trying to learn, using this sample application.

```
[DataContract]
        internal class Person
        {
            [DataMember]
            internal string name;

            [DataMember]
            internal int age;
        }

    String strData = "{ \"Person\": [{\"name\":\"TSR\",\"age\": 4 },{\"name\":\"KV\",\"age\":10}]}";
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData));
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
    Person jsonArray = (Person)ser.ReadObject(ms) as Person;
```

I was testing the program by giving a sample input as this. Note the last curley bracket is missing in the input. I was expecting the program to throw some sort of exception but it's not. Is this an expected behavior with System.JSON?

`"{ \"Person\": [{\"name\":\"TSR\",\"age\": 4 },{\"name\":\"KV\",\"age\":10}]";`

The below input has an extra curley brace at the end. No exception is thrown for this input as well.

`"{ \"Person\": [{\"name\":\"TSR\",\"age\": 4 },{\"name\":\"KV\",\"age\":10}]}}";`

Comment: There is no `System.JSON`.  `DataContractJsonSerializer` is in the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` namespace.

Comment: I think even Microsoft has given up on their own JSON implementation these days, in favor of JSON.NET. They certainly have for ASP.NET MVC. Unless you really need the very specific serialization semantics that `DataContractJsonSerializer` has (as with object graphs, for example) I wouldn't bother with it, or worry about its quirks.

Comment: Yes, I am referencing System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

Answer (score 0):

Tell System.Json to Parse your string to a JsonValue. If it's valid, it will pass - if not, it should throw an exception

```
try
{
    var validJson = JsonValue.Parse(strData);
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
    //Invalid Json Format
    Console.WriteLine(e);
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    //some other exception
}
```

Comment: JsonValue is not part of System.Runtime.Serialization.json.

Comment: @Shashi My apologies, my answer is using Windows.Data.Json. I had my namespaces mixed up.

Comment: Thanks. But I have to use System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace.